# how to redirect old url with parameters to new seo url using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

want to redirect param urls to seo friendly urls

`https://example.com/a.php?slug=vr-promised-us-the-future-too-bad-we-re-stuck-in-the-present`

to

`https://example.com/vr-promised-us-the-future-too-bad-we-re-stuck-in-the-present`

and

`https://example.com/tag.php?id=Virtual-reality`

to

`https://example.com/tag/Virtual-reality`

my current .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ a.php?slug=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: This htaccess is still dynamic (multi domains) and no domain is writing on a hard way.So don't change it and add the site domain using CNAME from hosting management and add vhost to point to the new local folder.

Comment: @headmax thanks for response, actually my question is how to block duplicate url (redirect old =>  /a.php?slug=vr-promised-us-the-future-too-bad-we-re-stuck-in-the-present to /vr-promised-us-the-future-too-bad-we-re-stuck-in-the-present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

# external redirect to redirect old URL to pretty URL    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /a\.php\?slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /tag\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^tag/([\w-]+)/?$ tag.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal rewrite to forward to actual URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ a.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Edited the answer.